# Why won't my images center using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to html/css and am trying to make a straight-forward webpage, which is just several images centered horizontally, each on their own row. I ended up using Bootstrap's basic html template, and can't figure out what's wrong with the code below. My images are stuck on the left edge of the page. The only CSS I'm currently using is the default linked one: "css/bootstrap.min.css"

This is all that's currently in my body:

```
<div class=“container-fluid”>

  <div class=“row”>
      <img src="..." class=“img-responsive center-block”>
  </div>

  <div class=“row”>
      <img src="..." class=“img-responsive center-block”>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which exact version of Bootstrap are you using? Your example should work, as far as I can tell, in Boostrap 3.0.1+. Also, hopefully your actual markup doesn't contain curly quotes.

Comment: I changed my link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> ` so I'm confused as well why it's not working.

Comment: All I did was paste [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) into a TextEdit document and changed the Hello World line to what's in my original post. And also now replaced the link. I haven't downloaded or installed anything, is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotation marks ("") seem to be broken in your img's class. Don't know what your actually using but change them to normal quotation marks and it should work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
      <img src="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <img src="..." class="img-responsive center-block">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to turn off Smart Quotations in TextEdit's options. I had no knowledge of that feature and its negative effect when writing html.